# Postgres archiving status from sys tables

Tags: postgresql

I need a way to know what is the archiving status of the PG - how many files have been archived? How many are left to be archived? Has the archiving been failing or succeeding?

Also, the checkpointing information or something which might be going wrong with PG?

I would like to know if there is a sys table/view which has this information?

Answer (score 1):

The system view [**`pg_stat_archiver`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ARCHIVER-VIEW) always shows a single row answering your questions:

> `archived_count` `bigint`
> Number of WAL files that have been successfully archived
>
> `last_archived_wal` `text`
> Name of the WAL file most recently successfully archived
>
> `last_archived_time` `timestamp with time zone`
> Time of the most recent successful archive operation
>
> `failed_count` `bigint`
> Number of failed attempts for archiving WAL files
>
> `last_failed_wal` `text`
> Name of the WAL file of the most recent failed archival operation
>
> `last_failed_time` `timestamp with time zone`
> Time of the most recent failed archival operation
>
> `stats_reset` `timestamp with time zone`
> Time at which these statistics were last reset

Comment: But this doesn't give me an insight on the number of WAL files still remaining to be archived.